# Random characters displayed after string - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, codeblocks

I am using codeblocks with GCC compiler to output a string containing an array, however after the string is printed, a random character is output at the end of the string (each time I build and compile the program the character changes).

My code:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 10
char buf[BUF_SIZE];

char a = 'a';
for (int i=0; i<BUF_SIZE; ++i)
{
    buf[i]= a;
    a++;
}
string s = buf;
cout << '[' << s << ']' << endl;
```

Output:

```
[abcdefghij"
]
```

I am also wondering why the closing square bracket is on a new line. I expected the output to just be "[abcdefhij]". I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: You seem to forget that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminated* bit is very important.

Comment: Also, if you're going to copy the C-style null-terminated byte string to a C++ `std::string` object anyway, why not append the characters directly to `s`? What's the use of `buf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` strings are really just C style  null-terminated strings. Add `'\0'` to terminate it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const size_t BUF_SIZE = 10; // consider size_t
    char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];     // +1 to make room for '\0'

    char a = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        buf[i] = a;
        a++;
    }
    buf[BUF_SIZE] = '\0';       // null terminate it
    string s = buf;
    cout << '[' << s << ']' << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[abcdefghij]
```

If all you want to do is adding `char`s to a string tho, you might directly use `push_back` on the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const size_t BUF_SIZE = 10;
    string s = "";
    char a = 'a';
    for (int i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        s.push_back(a++); // increments a and returns the previous value
    }
    cout << '[' << s << ']' << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In C++, when you use a character array as a string it must be null-terminated (end with '\0') so that we know how long it is. Try changing `char buf[BUF_SIZE]` to `char buf[BUF_SIZE+1]` and adding `buf[BUF_SIZE]='\0'` after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

C-Strings are null terminated, meaning they are terminated by a 0 value.

In this case if you wanted to output the first 10 characters of the alphabet you need to take into account this null termination character.

There are a few ways you could go about this, but the first thing you will need to do is account for the extra character in your buffer:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 10
char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];
```

Depending on your compiler this buffer memory may already be initialized to 0's, but it is best to never make assumptions.

Set the last value of the buffer to 0, to terminate the string:

```
buf[BUF_SIZE] = 0;
```

Then you can proceed with the remainder of the code you have already written, and you can just output the char array as a string.

```
char a = 'a';
for (int i=0; i<BUF_SIZE; ++i) {
    buf[i]= a;
    a++;
}

cout << '[' << buf << ']' << endl;
```

The important thing is just setting the end of the string to 0. When you were casting your char array to a string this value likely got corrupted and there was random values in the memory before it came to this 0 value.